# How to concatenate many txt files with different names into one array with numpy on python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have files with the following convention for names

```
acc_exp01_user01 
acc_exp02_user01
acc_exp03_user02
acc_exp04_user02
acc_exp05_user03
acc_exp06_user03
and so on...
```

Notice that for each experiment numbering, they share the same user with 1 other.

How do I iterate through all the txt files and concatenate them into 1 array using numpy on python?

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command prompt to do that in one line.

You need to be in the directory where your txt files are.

So use the command: `cd /path_to_the_txt_files/`

Windows:

```
C:\> type acc_exp0* > one_big_file
```

Linux:

```
$ cat acc_exp0* > out_big_file
```

The you read `one_big_file` in python with

```
data = []
with open('one_big_file.txt', 'w') as file:  
    for line in file:
        data.append(line)
```